# How to change column order in tbl_summary() in R

Tags: r, summary, gtsummary

I am using tbl_summary in R to create a table, but I do not like the default ordering of the columns.

````
```
tbl9 <- DH_df2 %>% select(Age_Group, BOP_Level)
tbl9 %>%
  tbl_summary(by = Age_Group,
  missing = "no") %>%
  add_p(everything() ~ "chisq.test") %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Age Groups**") %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1. Correlation Age and BOP**") %>%
  bold_labels()
```
````

My output gives me the correct information and table, but I want to move "Under 35" to be the come before "Age36~50". How can I do that?

Current Column output: Age Groups / Age36~50 / Age51~ / Under 35 / p-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to define the order of the by variable levels is to make your by variable a factor with the levels in the order you'd like them to appear.

PS if you provide reproducible examples in your posts (i.e. code we can all run on our machines), you'll get more detailed solutions.

Comment: Thank you! I am still figuring out StackOverflow so I haven't figured that out yet. but your website has been super helpful in my project.

Comment: This works, but there is a slight problem. It seems that add_difference always computes the first level minus the second level. But say you want the columns ordered Pre Post, but you want the difference calculated Post - Pre?? I can't figure that one out.

Comment: Too late to edit my comment - found an answer to reversing the order of columns after the difference is computed

  # switch the order of the columns
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x |> dplyr::relocate(stat_2, .before = stat_1)
  )

Comment: Example code for leveling the factor by variable: `tbl9 %>% mutate(Age_Group = factor(Age_Group, levels = c("Under 35", "Age36~50", "Age51")))`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `relocate` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
tbl9 <- tbl9 %>%
relocate(` Under 35`, .before = `Age36~50`)
```

Answer (score -2):

https://statisticsglobe.com/reorder-columns-of-data-frame-in-r

These are the basic methods (taken from above link).

- use the indexing operator:
  `data[ , c(2, 1, 3)]`         with index
  `data[ , c("x2", "x1", "x3")]` with names
- use subset:
  `subset(data, select = c(2, 1, 3))`
- use dplyrs select function:
  `data %>% select(x2, x1, x3)`